# Different icons for multiple Select2 dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am currently using Select2 to make my dropdowns searchable. I have gotten to the point of where I can change the icon but now when I am calling Select2 on another drop-down and change the icon it shows up twice. This is the code I have at the moment;

```
    $(".where__heading").select2({
        placeholder: "Try 'Belfast'",
        allowClear: false,
    });
    $('b[role="presentation"]').hide();
    $('.select2-selection__arrow').append('<img src="images/icons/travel.svg" alt="">');

   Calling in it again below on a different dropdown....

    $(".how__long").select2({
        placeholder: "1-2 days",
        allowClear: false,
    });
    $('b[role="presentation"]').hide();
    $('.select2-selection__arrow').append('<img src="images/icons/time.svg" alt="">');
```

---

I can't seem to figure this out. Do I just need to make this more precise;

```
$('.select2-selection__arrow').append('<img src="images/icons/time.svg" alt="">');
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Could you add this in a demo ? , another case i think he refresh her list so may have a function you can control this event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be more precise. Something like this would work.

```
$('.where__heading').next().find('span.select2-selection__arrow').append('<img src="images/icons/travel.svg" alt="">');
$('.how__long').next().find('span.select2-selection__arrow').append('<img src="images/icons/time.svg" alt="">');
```